# Why so many cases in vue js?

Tags: vue.js

I came across [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case). [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names) and for components as well.

Why so many compatibility things, conversion things, error cases when specifying different cases? Isn't so easy to have only one common case?

I am new to `vue` and learning it. Could someone enlighten me to handle cases in a better way? Which case should be used when and what conversion it does/doesn't?

> Unlike components and props, event names don’t provide any automatic case transformation.

> Name of an emitted event must exactly match the name used to listen to that event

> when you’re using in-DOM templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased (hyphen-delimited) equivalents

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Comment: As you can see from my answer, there are more  facts than opionions. I think this question is useful to understand the underlying mechanism of vue.

Comment: Your answer is off-topic as well. It doesn't answer the question: which is "why". The only person who could answer this question objectively is (probably) Evan You. Anyone else would be speculating, which is pretty much what your answer is doing.

Comment: You really think that this does not answer his question? "We’re simply following the conventions of each language. Within JavaScript, camelCase is more natural. Within HTML, kebab-case is." for example? My answers are taken from the Official Vue Style guide, so not much speculating.

Answer (score 3):

The vue style guide gives some reasons, [for what concerns **props**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Prop-name-casing-strongly-recommended):

> We’re simply following the conventions of each language. Within
> JavaScript, camelCase is more natural. Within HTML, kebab-case is.

for [single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Single-file-component-filename-casing-strongly-recommended):

> PascalCase works best with autocompletion in code editors, as it’s
> consistent with how we reference components in JS(X) and templates,
> wherever possible. However, mixed case filenames can sometimes create
> issues on case-insensitive file systems, which is why kebab-case is
> also perfectly acceptable.

[about DOM templates:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-name-casing-in-templates-strongly-recommended)

> Unfortunately, due to HTML’s case insensitivity, DOM templates must
> still use kebab-case.

Following, a quick view of suggested case naming and caveats:

**Props and components**: when we talk about props (and component), define them camelCase and use them kebab-case. eg:

define

```
...
props: [myProp],
...
```

and use like:

```
<component my-prop="something"
```

**Events** for them the logic is pretty much the opposite, **with a caveat to remember**, when you listen for them, they are just lower case

eg. **Emit** the event:

```
$emit('my-Event')
```

listen to the event

```
<component @my-event="eventHandler" // works

<component @my-Event="eventHandler" // Does not work
```

or

```
$emit('myEvent')
```

and to listen:

```
<component @myevent="eventHandler" // works

<component @myEvent="eventHandler" // Does not work
```

That's why in the vue docs is suggested to directly use kebab case for events, to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Note that in the Vue 2 docs yes it recommends kebab case, but there seems to be no mention of this in the new vue3 docs, they mention a mix of camelCase and kebab-case. (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names vs https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events

Comment: It's not intuitive for me to emit something like "aRegularEvent" and bind the handler to "@a-regular-event". This is the number 1 reason why I don't like Vue.